# Unable to start debugging. No terminal is available to launch the debugger. Please install Gnome Terminal or XTerm

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug simple hello world using visual studio code. How can set terminal path in my debugger settings file? I am using following settings.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch (GDB)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "launchOptionType": "Local",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/hello.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true
        },
        {
            "name": "C++ Attach (GDB)",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "launchOptionType": "Local",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "targetArchitecture": "x64",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/hello.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "processId": "enter program's process ID",
            "externalConsole": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like they're hard coded in [the source](https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine/blob/2187999976a8606700097b649d2ffb2b3ff070a5/src/MICore/TerminalLauncher.cs) as `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` and `/usr/bin/xterm` . Do you not have those files?

Comment: I am checking out the source right now and I have also opened issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9231.

Comment: I meant, do you not have either of those two applications installed? If you don't, they're usually easy to install if you have administrator access on the Linux system.

Comment: When i echo $TERM it returns xterm but it is not present in /usr/bin.

Comment: Here is the code that set terminal in vscode 'let defaultTerminalLinux = 'xterm';
if (env.isLinux) {
 if (fs.existsSync('/etc/debian_version')) {
  defaultTerminalLinux = 'x-terminal-emulator';
 } else if (process.env.DESKTOP_SESSION === 'gnome' || process.env.DESKTOP_SESSION === 'gnome-classic') {
  defaultTerminalLinux = 'gnome-terminal';
 } else if (process.env.COLORTERM) {
  defaultTerminalLinux = process.env.COLORTERM;
 } else if (process.env.TERM) {
  defaultTerminalLinux = process.env.TERM;
 }
}' I have tried to update TERM on vscode shell but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is easy, open up a terminal and type the following commands:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s ./{your_terminal} xterm
```

Comment: I'm glad this symbolic link fix works on your machine but with Fedora 25 and VSCode 1.8.0-insider, symbolically linking xterm to /usr/bin/konsole and then launching the cppdbg debugger from VSCode results in a 10 second delay followed by error message "Unable to start debugging. Failed to initialize debugger terminal."

Comment: A little tweak is needed for Debian 9/VSCode 1.28.1/mate-terminal 1.16.3: `ln -s /usr/bin/mate-terminal.wrapper xterm`

Answer (score 0):

Create this /usr/bin/xterm script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/konsole -e 'bash -c "$6"'
```

Works fine in VSCode. A symlink won't work because of the quoting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading this, please note bash, zsh, fish, starship etc are cli tools not terminal emulators. Go to VS Code > Settings > Terminal External and change it to a terminal emulators like XTerm, Konsole, Gnome-Terminal. bash, zsh etc. won't work as they just read/write to stdin/stdout and emulate commands. Terminal Emulators complete the interface by providing stdin/stdout and probably stderr to the cli-tools. Peace.